# Grabbing form data from a table to format for email

Tags: php, html

I have a table form that I need to grab data from and them format it so I can send it in an html email and make it readable.  I have multiple tables like this one as well as mixture of lone text and checkbox fields as well.  I need a script that can read the data in the table as well as the lone text fields and checkboxes and format it in an html email.

So 1)I need a way to read the data entered into the table and format it into the email once read

2)How can I set the script up to tell when it's hit a table and when it's just on a field by itself.

```
           <!----------------Lone feilds--------------------->

            <label for="name_insured">Named Insured(s):
        <input type="text" name="name_insured" size="74" />
        </label>

        <label for="mailing_address">Mailing Address:
        <input type="text" name="mailing_address" size="74"/>
        </label>

            <!------------Check boxes-------------------------->
            <input type="checkbox" name="NATA_NBAA_HAI_AOPA_OTHER_member" value="yes"/>Yes

        <input type="checkbox" name="NATA_NBAA_HAI_AOPA_OTHER_member" value="no"/>No

    <input type="checkbox" name="NATA_NBAA_HAI_AOPA_OTHER_member" value="other"/>Other

    <!------------Table------------------------>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Pilots Names</th>
            <th>Birth Date</th>
            <th>CML</th>
            <th>ATP</th>
            <th>ME</th>
            <th>Total Time</th>
            <th>Multi-Eng</th>
            <th>Complex</th>
            <th>Turbine</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pilot_name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth_date" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="CML" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ATP" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ME" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total_time" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="multi_eng" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="complex" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="turbine" size="5"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pilot_name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth_date" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="CML" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ATP" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ME" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total_time" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="multi_eng" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="complex" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="turbine" size="5"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pilot_name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth_date" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="CML" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ATP" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ME" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total_time" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="multi_eng" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="complex" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="turbine" size="5"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pilot_name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth_date" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="CML" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ATP" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ME" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total_time" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="multi_eng" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="complex" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="turbine" size="5"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pilot_name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth_date" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="CML" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ATP" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ME" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total_time" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="multi_eng" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="complex" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="turbine" size="5"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pilot_name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth_date" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="CML" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ATP" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ME" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total_time" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="multi_eng" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="complex" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="turbine" size="5"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pilot_name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth_date" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="CML" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ATP" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ME" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total_time" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="multi_eng" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="complex" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="turbine" size="5"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pilot_name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth_date" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="CML" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ATP" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ME" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total_time" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="multi_eng" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="complex" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="turbine" size="5"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pilot_name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth_date" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="CML" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ATP" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ME" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total_time" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="multi_eng" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="complex" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="turbine" size="5"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pilot_name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth_date" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="CML" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ATP" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ME" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total_time" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="multi_eng" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="complex" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="turbine" size="5"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pilot_name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth_date" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="CML" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ATP" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ME" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total_time" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="multi_eng" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="complex" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="turbine" size="5"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pilot_name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth_date" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="CML" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ATP" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ME" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total_time" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="multi_eng" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="complex" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="turbine" size="5"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pilot_name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth_date" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="CML" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ATP" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ME" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total_time" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="multi_eng" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="complex" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="turbine" size="5"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pilot_name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth_date" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="CML" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ATP" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ME" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total_time" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="multi_eng" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="complex" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="turbine" size="5"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pilot_name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="birth_date" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="CML" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ATP" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ME" value="yes"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total_time" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="multi_eng" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="complex" size="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="turbine" size="5"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This is the script I have right now, but It only prints the data in a really long line and for the data from the table, they have the same names so it overides the last entry with the same name.  I've thought of putting numbers after each field with the same name but it still is hard to read.

```
foreach( $_POST as $name=>$value){  
         $emailMsg .=  "<b>" .  htmlspecialchars(var2Readable($name)) . ': ' . "</b>" . htmlspecialchars(clean4Email($value)) . "<br />
 }
```

Comment: Yes you definitely should look at arrays, if there are going to be 100's of users or more each entering unique details you should look at multidimensional arrays, and possibly a MySQL database to store the entries.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this what you are looking for but if you want to get the values of all the checkboxes and text fields you must give them a name ending with a [].
For Eg.
name="pilot_name[]"
name="turbine[]"

This will give you an array containing all the pilot names,turbines etc. that were posted.
now can iterate with an incremental variable in a for loop.